# Specifying a LIMIT clause in a JPA2 repository @Query statement

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have the following MySQL statement:

```
  "SELECT * FROM $this->tableName WHERE news_publication_id = '" + newsPublicationId + "' AND list_order > '" + listOrder +"' ORDER BY list_order LIMIT 1"
```

I started on the data handling path by first doing an Hibernate DAO layer.

It had the following criteria based method:

```
  @Override
  public NewsHeading findNextWithListOrder(NewsPublication newsPublication, int listOrder) {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(getPersistentClass());
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("newsPublication", newsPublication));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.gt("listOrder", listOrder)).addOrder(Order.asc("listOrder")).setMaxResults(1);
    return (NewsHeading) criteria.uniqueResult();
  }
```

And it works just fine.

Then I tried doing a JPA2 repository layer.

It now has the following JPQL based method:

```
  @Query("SELECT nh FROM NewsHeading nh WHERE nh.newsPublication = :newsPublication AND nh.listOrder > :listOrder ORDER BY nh.listOrder ASC LIMIT 1")
  public NewsHeading findByNextListOrder(@Param("newsPublication") NewsPublication newsPublication, @Param("listOrder") int listOrder);
```

But it doesn't work. Because the LIMIT clause is not valid.

So I wonder what to do.

Can I still use the criteria based method of above in this JPA2 repository layer ?

I would like to avoid trusting the client to pass the limit value and prefer to hard code that value (of 1) into my layer.

Also, that statement returns only one object and so there is no pagination needed.

Any tip would be most welcomed.

Kind Regards,

Stephane Eybert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably this with a `PageRequest`.  http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.2.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.core-concepts

Hibernate wants you to do `setMaxResults()` on the `Query` object, but JPA doesn't interface with that directly.

Other option would be to use a `@NamedNativeQuery`

Comment: I was reluctant to use the PageRequest as it places an additional method in between. I could otherwise use the @NamedNativeQuery option with a specific one for each platform. Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to have a NewsStoryRepositoryCustom interface whose implementation would define the public NewsStory findByNextListOrder(NewsPaper newsPaper, NewsHeading newsHeading, int listOrder) method. But using the PageRequest is not what I'd like since there is no pagination, no several objects. Only one object is to be returned with the limit 1 clause. Any way to use a Sort without using a PageRequest ?

Comment: Yes you can Sort w/o a PageRequest, but both ways using Spring JPA do not use custom queries. If you are going to use a @NamedNativeQuery you can just have the `order by` clause specified there.

Comment: You'd have a tip or link to using Sort without any PageRequest ?

Comment: Here is an example that I have used in my repository interface.  `List<Category> findAll(@NotNull Sort sort);`

Comment: You can also use it right in the name of the method.  `List<Person> findByLastnameOrderByFirstnameAsc(String lastname);`